# How to compare 2 directory by using netbean8 IDE?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I wanted to compare the code between 2 different directory. In Sublime Text there is a plugin available called Sublime Merge which can compare 2 diff dir but Sublime Text is not open source like Netbean8. I have done lots of goggle to find similar solution in Netbean8. 
Is there any similar plugin available in Netbean8?

I have also tried to use WinMerge but that do not work properly here. Also tried linux diff command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this? https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/netbeans-quick-tip-10-diffing-two-files